# Python 2.7 Ineritance get parent method properties

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie and have confused learning OOP on python. I am trying to inherit class also using super, but it didn't work as expected.

here my code.

> parent.py

```
class Sale(http.Controller):

    def cart(self, **post):
        order = request.website.sale_get_order()
        ....
        return request.render("website_sale.cart", values)
```

> child.py

```
import Sale as sale

class SaleExtend(sale):

    def cart(self, **post):
        if order:
        # do something
    ....

    return super(SaleExtend, self).cart(**post)
```

I got an error,

```
AttributeError: 'Sale (extended by SaleExtend)' object has no attribute 'order'
```

if I just use `pass` its work correctly, but how to get `order` value from a parent?

or I did it wrong.

Comment: indentation errors, `self.order` ... simply `order` inside a funciton is function scope and gone if you leave the function. Read about [scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: You haven't defined an instance variable `order` anywhere, merely a local variable

Comment: @PatrickArtner same happen.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's on the parent.

Comment: @DickyRaambo no, **you never define an instance variable `order` anywhere**. Where do you think that is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no **instance** nor a **class variable** `order`:

> ```
> class Sale(http.Controller):
>
>     def cart(self, **post):
>         # FUNCTION SCOPE - exists only inside the function
>         order = request.website.sale_get_order()  
>         ....
>         return request.render("website_sale.cart", values)
> ```

Class variables are created like so:

```
class Ale():
    content = "Lager"     # this is shared between all instances -> "static"
```

Instance variables are created like so:

```
class Ale():
    def __init__(self, ale_type):
        self.content = ale_type       # this is different for each instance unless you 
                                      # create multiple instances with the same ale_type
                                      # but they are still "independent" of each other
```

Function scope variables are creates like so:

```
class Ale():

    # ....

    def doSomething(self):
        lenContent = len(self.content)      # function scope
        print( self.content, lenContent )

    def doElse(self):
        print(lenContent)   # NameError - does not exist in scope
```

See [Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)  and [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)